# New account creation and deploying to node

Tags: light-clients, eth-lightwallet

I am developing lightwallet and trying to create new address (account) on custom node. Already tried to use eth-lightwallet and ethereumjs-accounts. I don't understand how to deploy new account to node. I created accounts, but it stored in browser only.

```
 $("new").onclick = function() {
                console.log($("new_passphrase").value);

                var newAccount = Accounts.new($("new_passphrase").value);
                $("new_result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newAccount, null, 2);
            };
```

Also I need to send coins from one address to another. Can you give some exaples how to add account to done and synchronise browser accounts with node accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the network's perspective, it's actually not a CREATE process but rather a RECLAIM process: all the accounts are already there, on creating the account from eth-lightwallet, you got the private key to access the address derived from that key.